# Casperjs: testing jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, casperjs, browser-automation, browser-testing

I'm having trouble interacting with a jquery auto-complete input box with casperjs.  I've tried many different ways, but I can't seem to select the auto complete option when the list of options pops up.

My code is as follows:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
  $('#myInput').val('cars');  // fill in the text box
  $('#myInput').blur();  // should trigger the autocomplete ajax call
  $('.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item:nth-of-type(1)').click(); // should click the first item in the list
});

// take a picture to make sure it worked
casper.then(function() {
  this.captureSelector('pics/test1.png', '#theForm');
});
```

This doesn't work at all, even though it looks like it should.  By playing around with it, I've found that triggering a down arrow keypress a few times triggers the auto complete to show up, so here is a version that is closer to working.  This works in the browser, but not in a casper.thenEvaluate block for some reason.

```
$('#myInput').val('cars');  // fill in the text box
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 40; // press down arrow a few times, not sure why this works
$("#myInput").trigger(e);
$("#myInput").trigger(e);
$('.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item:nth-of-type(1)').click();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not based on jQuery UI's autocomplete, but rather Typeahead which is related to Bootstrap, but the mechanics should be the same.

I have had success with the following:

```
casper.sendKeys("#field_departure_airport", 'a', {keepFocus: true});
casper.waitUntilVisible(".typeahead", function() {
    casper.click(".typeahead>li:nth-child(1)>a");
    test.assertField("departure_airport", "A. L. Mangham Jr. Regional Airport(Nacogdoches, Texas, United States) [OCH]"); 
});
```

This runs in a `casper.then()` function, the `sendKeys` selects a field by ID and passes "a" to it. The `keepFocus` is important, otherwise it will deselect the input after inserting the text!

Wait for `.typeahead` to appear, that waits for the AJAX call to the server, then click the first `a` element in the Typeahead.

And lastly test the value of the field. Note that the field selector is its *name*, not a CSS3 selector.

Comment: my implementation was different, but this gave the clues I needed.

Comment: Did you try with the second child of your <li>? -> :nth-child(2), because i have a similar issue and whatever i do, it always takes my first li... so only the first li-element of auto-complete.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of different solutions, which didn't work, or not always. I've finally found one which seems robust :

```
/*
 * You have to specify the input selector, the text you want to write in (which activates the auto-completion), and the text on which you want to click
 */
casper.fillAutoCompletion = function (inputSelector, text, autoCompleteText) {
    //keepfocus : true to keep the auto-completion opened
    this.sendKeys(inputSelector, text, {keepFocus: true});
    //wait for the auto-complete block to appear
    this.waitUntilVisible("[class*='ui-autocomplete']", function() {
        var x = require('casper').selectXPath
            ,xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'" + autoCompleteText + "')]"
            ;
    //move on the wanted element and click
    this.mouse.move(x(xpath));
    this.click(x(xpath));
    });
};
```

Or if you don't prefer to extend, js function :

```
var fillAutoCompletion = function (inputSelector, text, autoCompleteText) {
    //keepfocus : true to keep the auto-completion opened
    casper.sendKeys(inputSelector, text, {keepFocus: true});
    //wait for the auto-complete block to appear
    casper.waitUntilVisible("[class*='ui-autocomplete']", function() {
        var x = require('casper').selectXPath
            ,xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'" + autoCompleteText + "')]"
            ;
    //move on the wanted element and click
    casper.mouse.move(x(xpath));
    casper.click(x(xpath));
    });
};
```

Call it :

```
.thenOpen("yourUrl", function(){
    this.fillAutoCompletion(".jODMainSearch","Ren", "Rennes");//extending
    fillAutoCompletion(".jODMainSearch","Par", "Paris");//js
})
```

The trick (for me) was to use mouse.move() on the wanted element (to activate its selection) before clicking on it, otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest nesting the `sendKeys` inside a `then` block, because calling `fillAutoCompletion` after you've done some navigation using previous steps the `sendKeys` might be executed before the target page is even visible. After the change you could move `fillAutoCompletion` out of and after the `thenOpen` block.

Comment: You are everywhere :p , you mean use it that way : `.thenOpen().fillAutoCompletion().then().wait() ..... ?` It doesn't work. I've got into the habit to nest my custom functions in individual step functions, because I'm not the only one to read my tests, that way they know when it's a native function or not. But yeah I agree; to execute a custom function in a closure it's better to nest it with a step function.

Comment: Pure luck :) Yes, I mean it (nearly) this way: `casper.thenOpen; fillAutoCompletion(); casper.then();`. Nesting is ok as long as you know that you cannot do more steps after `thenOpen`, because they have to be also nested.

Comment: Ok I see, but I prefer chaining instructions, it does the same but I find this way lighter :p, and apparently casper doesn't like when we chain a custom function. Also thenOpen() wait for the DOM to be loaded and js functions to be executed before executing the first instruction, so for me there is no prob for fillAutoCompletion() in a thenOpen()-maybe for you too, I may have misunderstood your last sentence- . But we agree a `this.click()`-if it affects our input- `+ this.fillAutoCompletion()` must be monitored without nesting :p